# Migrating specific columns (almost 250) from one Excel workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Migrating data from one workbook to other. In new workbook I want only specific columns (that are almost 250). As the data in Master file, is inconsistent and not in same range, so how can I extract those 250 columns? As, I am new to VBA, I have tried the code below, it's working but I have to write long code for all that 250 columns? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Data_Migration()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set y = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0



Set x = Workbooks.Open("file path")
 'Column Q from master file with worksheet name cba is copied in new workbook with sheet name abc and pasted in column D
Set ws = y.Sheets("abc")
Set sh = x.Sheets("cba")
Set rng = sh.Range("Q2:Q11443") 
rng.Copy
y.Sheets("abc").Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Set ws = y.Sheets("abc")
Set sh = x.Sheets("cba")
Set rng = sh.Range("Z2:Z11443") 
rng.Copy
y.Sheets("abc").Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Set ws = y.Sheets("abc")
Set sh = x.Sheets("cba")
Set rng = sh.Range("AI2:AI11443") 
rng.Copy
y.Sheets("abc").Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

x.Close
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the following code into a standard code module (by default 'Module1' but you can name it to your liking).

```
Sub Main()
    ' 21 Mar 2017

    Dim WsS As Worksheet                        ' S = Source
    Dim WbT As Workbook, WsT As Worksheet       ' T = Target
    Dim Cs As Long, Ct As Long                  ' Column numbers: Source & Target
    Dim Clms As Variant
    Dim i As Integer                            ' index for Clms

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ErrExit
    ' Source is the first worksheet in the active workbook:
    Set WsS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Haseev")
    Set WbT = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set WsT = WbT.Worksheets(1)
    WsT.Name = "Extract 250"                    'name the target sheet

    Clms = Array(1, 4, 8, 13)                   ' list column numbers < 17
    For i = 0 To UBound(Clms)
        CopyColumn WsS, WsT, Clms(i), Ct
    Next i

    For Cs = 17 To Columns("CHU").Column Step 9
        CopyColumn WsS, WsT, Cs, Ct
''''        If Ct > 10 Then Exit For
    Next Cs
ErrExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Understand the code:-
Make the currently active workbook the "Source", meaning you must look at the workbook from which you are about to copy data. The code expects to find a worksheet by the name of "Haseev" in this workbook. Change the name in the code or change that entire line of code to

```
Set WsS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

That specifies the first worksheet in the workbook which makes good sense because a large workbook like yours isn't likely to have too many sheets.

The code will create a new workbook with a single sheet in it. It will name that sheet "Extract 250". Change the name in the code to something you prefer.
Next, the code will copy selected columns to the new workbook.

```
Clms = Array(1, 4, 8, 13)
```

You can specify which columns you want to copy - as many as you need, numbers separated by commas. If you don't want any, just leave the specification blank, like Clms = Array()

In the next loop every 9th column is copied, starting from column 17 to column "CHU". You can modify the "CHU". The line

```
''''        If Ct > 10 Then Exit For
```

is a leftover from my testing. You may like to use it for the same purpose. Remove the apostrophes which disable the code and the loop will stop copying after 10 columns have been copied to the new workbook.

You may notice that the above code doesn't contain any copy or paste. Instead, it calls the next sub which you should paste below the Main procedure you already copied above.

```
Private Sub CopyColumn(WsS As Worksheet, _
                       WsT As Worksheet, _
                       ByVal Cs As Long, _
                       Ct As Long)
    ' 21 Mar 2017
    ' Ct is a return Long

    If Cs > 0 Then              ' column number must be > 0
        Ct = Ct + 1
        WsS.Columns(Cs).Copy Destination:=WsT.Columns(Ct)
    End If

End Sub
```

Basically, the Main procedure just manages the 250 plus times this sub will be called.

The output workbook will have a generic name given by Excel, like "Sheet1". You can save it under any name you wish or close it and make a new one next time you wish to look at it.

Comment: It works completely fine. Appreciate your guidance and kind support !

Answer (score 0):

You need a For ..  Next loop. Basically,

```
Dim C As Long
For C = 1 to 250
    ' enter repetitive code here
Next C
```

If C is your column number, you can use C as the column number instead of "A", "B", "C". Excel isn't very good at letters. It converts the A you type into 1, B to 2, C to 3 etc - up to 250.

However, it seems that you don't need consecutive columns. So, you create an array of the numbers you need.

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Array(1, 12, 16, 25, 32)  ' list all your 250 columns.
```

Now, Arr(0) = 1, Arr(1) = 12, Arr(2) = 16 etc.
and you construct your loop to refer to these numbers.

```
Dim n As Integer
For n = 0 to Ubound(Arr)    ' that the number of elements in Arr
    C = Arr(n)
    Debug.Print C      ' this will write C in the immediate window
Next n
```

In this structure you can use C as the column number, like,

```
Set Rng = Sh.Range(Cells(3, C), Cells(11443, C))
```

Cells(3, C) specifies A3, if C = 1

PS Just occurred to me that you might need this, too:-
Range("ZH2").Column should return the column number for column "ZH"

Comment: I have tried, but the problem is that, there are 2257 columns in Master file and I only need 250 out of it. From column Q (17) i need every next 9th column till column CHU (2257).

Comment: That's easy, then. Build your loop as For C = 17 To 2257 Step 9

Comment: On every loop you copy the same data:-

Comment: On every loop you copy the same data from column Q: Set Rng = sh.Range("Q2:CHM11443"). This might be Set Rng = sh.Range(Cells(2, C), Cells(11443, C)) to pick up a single column as specified by the loop. Of course, you must also specify the destination for a single column. I think you can specify a single cell, such as y.Sheets("abc").cells(Clm, 1). Then you have to manage the variable Clm which would be = 2 on the first look and increases by one for every successive loop. Do this with Clm = Clm + 1.

Comment: There is  an automation error in executing this; `Set rng = sh.Range(Cells(2, C), Cells(11443, C))`

Comment: I know there is an error in my code but just for your info, thats the code; 
       `Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test.xlsx")
        Set ws = y.Sheets("abc")
        Set sh = x.Sheets("cba")
        For C = 17 To 55 Step 9
        Set rng = sh.Range(Cells(2, C), Cells(11443, C))
        rng.Copy
        y.Sheets("abc").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlValue
        Clm = Clm + 1
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        x.Close
        Next C
        End Sub`

Comment: Why do you want to copy rows 2:11443 in each column? Why exclude row 1? Why not copy the entire column?

Comment: Because row 1 is same for all the columns, thats why I want to copy rows 2:11443 .

Comment: Understood. But it takes extra effort to treat it differently. Do you have actually, precisely and invariably 11443 rows in your table? Or does this number have its own secret as well?

Comment: There is 11443 rows in table.

Comment: I have tried the code, for copying specific columns from another workbook. e.g. I am copying column Q from main workbook (cba) to column D in new workbook (abc);  `Set ws = y.Sheets("abc")
        Set sh = x.Sheets("cba")
        Set rng = sh.Range("Q2:Q11443" & lastrow) ' AS
        rng.Copy
        y.Sheets("abc").Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False`                                                     it's working completely fine but I have to write this code repetatively for 250 times to extract the 250 columns !